# Windows/Cygwin equivalents of linux screen and $()?

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin

I have a bash script that runs `screen` and uses `$( command )` to execute the output of `command`. I need to port this script to run on Windows. I installed Cygwin to run this but it doesn't recognize `screen` as a command and I don't know the Windows equivalent of linux's `$()`. Any suggestions on how to do this in windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

screen is not installed by default. 
You need to explicitly install it using cygwin setup.
https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.setup.what-packages

`$( command )` it is available in bash on Cygwin like on Linux